# How to create a load more button in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

I have cards and modals, I need to only show 2 cards in the page and have a button to show the rest, I’m new in programming and react, I don’t know what I have to do, that’s what I have now,

```
import React from "react"
import { Container } from "./_styles"
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import ImgMediaCard from "./../../../components/Cartao"
import AlertDialog from './../../../components/Modal'

export default function PortfolioSection(props) {
  let arrayProjetos = props.projects;

  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = React.useState(0);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClickOpen = (id) => {
    setSelectedId(id);
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  let projetos = arrayProjetos.edges[selectedId].node.frontmatter;

  return (
    <Container>
        {arrayProjetos.edges.map(
            function criaCard(e, index){
                let title = e.node.frontmatter.name;
                let imageCard = e.node.frontmatter.images[0];
                return (
                    <>
                    <ImgMediaCard 
                    alt={title} 
                    imagetitle={title}
                    texttitle={title} 
                    src={imageCard}
                    click={() => handleClickOpen(index)}>
                    </ImgMediaCard>
                    </>
                )
            }
        )}
        <AlertDialog 
        imageModal={projetos.images[1]}
        open={open} 
        handleClose={handleClose}
        title={projetos.name}
        text={projetos.description} />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

I'm using hooks to open the right modal when I click the "See more" button in the card, its working ok, I have 6 cards now, but I can add more in the future. I just need to limit how many cards I see when I enter the page and have a button to show everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. API: you can add a `pagination` and `total` properties to your api call which returns 2 cards by default and you can handle the count of cards by increasing the `pagination` value. You may notice to add check to avoid situations like `count > total`.
2. UI: you can add `const [cardCount, setCardCount] = useState(2)`
   and map through your cards array until the `index` not greater than `cardCount` value:

   ```
   {arrayProjetos.edges.map((e, index) => { return index <= cardCount && <ImgMediaCard ... /> })}

   <Box display={cardCount === 2 ? 'none' : 'block'}>
     <Button 
   onClick={()=> arrayProjetos.edges.length - cardCount === 3 ? setCardCount(...cardCount - 1) : setCardCount(...cardCount - 2)}>See less</Button>
   </Box>
   <Box display={cardCount === arrayProjetos.edges.length ? 'none' : 'block'} >
     <Button
     onClick={() => arrayProjetos.edges.length - cardCount === 1 ? setCardCount(...cardCount + 1) : setCardCount(...cardCount + 2)}>See more </Button>
   </Box>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the cards?
You need to lazy load, if you are getting from a server, you can implement pagination, so the server sends back 2 cards every time (or based on a page data you send to server)
So every time you click the "load more" button, you fire a function who ask server for two more cards, and add the response to your cards js variable

Comment: I have a card component, i import the "card template" then im creating each card in the map function, data values (title, image, etc) are in an object array (arrayProjetos.edges).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nazar, I did something similar I guess:

```
const [showMore, setShowMore] = React.useState(false);

const clickShow = () => {
  setShowMore(oldValue => !oldValue);
  showMore ? setButtonText("Ver Mais >") : setButtonText("Ver Menos <");
};

arrayProjetos.edges.slice(0, showMore ? arrayProjetos.edges.lenght : 2).map(
        function criaCard(e, index){/*same thing here*/})
<button onClick={() => clickShow()}>{buttonText}</button>
```

I used slice to limit the array and a hook to change value

Comment: But when you click Show more can you make it like only load 3 more items? and when show less it will dissappear 3 items not back to the old value